# How to create tailwind.config.js in custom directory instead of root folder with init command

Tags: css, express, model-view-controller, tailwind-css

I am using below npx command to generate tailwind.config.js file, it is creating this file in root directory by default. I want to create it in custom /config folder. Could anyone please guide me.

Also wanted to know what all changes are needed for tailwind to work with config residing in custom folder.

```
npx tailwindcss init
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`init` command may accept one of [these](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/blob/master/src/cli.js#L148) flags - `-f` to create full tailwind config and `-p` to create it with additional `postcss.config.js`. You may change directory and create config file there - not sure is it good for you or not

```
cd config && npx tailwindcss init
```

Every path within your config file is relative so pay attention at `content` section. Also your compiler as well must have correct path to config file, for example `require('tailwindcss')('./config/tailwind.config.js')` - but it depends in a way you compile styles